# restarting shell process in buffer

Tags: shell, emacs, text-editors, elisp

In emacs, I often have multiple shell buffers open and use rename-buffer to keep track of them.  Sometimes I inadvertently close the shell by hitting too many ^D's, or I'm on a system that automatically times-out inactive shells.  Is there a way to start a new shell in the same buffer?  Because I have renamed the buffer from *shell* typing M-x shell will start a shell in a new *shell* buffer, not the current buffer.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: M-x shell will simply go to a buffer called *shell* if it exists or create a new *shell* buffer if not.  I'm trying to restart a shell in the current buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of M-x shell, run the following emacs lisp code using M-:

```
(shell (current-buffer))
```

Comment: For your `init.el`: `(defun restart-shell () (interactive) (shell (current-buffer)))`, which can be tied then to a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't perfect, but it gets you most of what you want.  Put this code in your `.emacs` startup file:

```
(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  "Added to shell-mode-hook.  This function runs every time function shell
starts a shell."
  (rename-buffer "My Shell" 'unique))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
```

Feel free to change the string `"My Shell"` to some other name.  If you do `M-x shell RET` while in the `My Shell` buffer, then the new shell starts in the same buffer.  Unfortunately, if you do it in another buffer, then you get a new buffer named `My Shell<2>`, which isn't so pretty.  I think the latter effect can be eliminated by [advising](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_212.html) function `shell`, so that it switches to buffer `My Shell` before actually running the real `shell` function.